# ListLinePlot without joined the data point

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have some data points in given below format:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {0.5, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 8.5}, {4, 10}, {0, 0}, {0.5, 
4}, {1, 7}, {2, 9.5}, {4, 12}, {0, 0}, {0.5, 5}, {1, 9}, {2, 
12}, {4, 18}};
```

[image: ListLinePlot[data]

How to plot these data in `ListLinePlot` without joining the line from last data point to first one (highlighted by yellow square)?

Comment: What code generated the plot?

Comment: ListLinePlot[data]

Comment: That makes no sense. The maximal y-value in `data` is 10, whereas on the plot it's 19.

Comment: Please post the **full code** that gave your output. With the given data, we can get [this](https://imgur.com/a/twIqe).

Comment: Shall `data` describe a single curve or 3? (In the latter case, the three curves would be equal.)

Comment: it describe 3 curve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[Split[data, #2 =!= {0, 0} &], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image: myplot.jpeg]

**Edit**

The problem with the 'real' data imported from [drive.google.com/open?id=1uXuPcB-ibTS3Q7d4EDluyz-JF-wm_CLL](http://drive.google.com/open?id=1uXuPcB-ibTS3Q7d4EDluyz-JF-wm_CLL) is merely one of 
machine precision versus exact values for {0,0} - the y-values of each 'split point' are very close to but not exactly zero.

*Mathematica* has a very nice command, [Chop](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html), which
'replaces approximate real numbers in expr that are close to zero by the exact integer 0.", and one way of solving the problem is as follows:

```
ListLinePlot[Split[Chop[data, 0.0001], #2 =!= {0, 0} &], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image: mynewplot.jpeg]

Data were imported with:

```
data = Import["glv.1to.5.txt", "Data"];
```

Comment: Thanks it working on data that is given here,  but it is not working on .txt imported data file?

Comment: @GopalVerma Can you supply a copy of the .txt file? (and, if possible, the code you use to import).

Comment: Pls. find the link of data file. I am using Import[filename.txt,"Data".] command for importing the data file. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uXuPcB-ibTS3Q7d4EDluyz-JF-wm_CLL

Comment: Thanks,It is working.

Comment: Can u suggest how to change the thickness of line joining the data point(or plot markers).

Comment: For plotmarkers, `PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 2}`, maybe.  For thickness, modify `PlotStyle`. For example `ListLinePlot[Split[Chop[data, 0.0001], #2 =!= {0, 0} &],  PlotMarkers -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Red, Thick], Orange, Green, 
   Directive[Cyan, Thick, Dashed]}]`.

Comment: Or, being adventurous, and plotting every fifth point: `ListLinePlot[
 Take[#, {1, -1, 5}] & /@ Split[Chop[data, 0.0001], #2 =!= {0, 0} &], 
 PlotTheme -> "Business"]`

Comment: Thanks @ tomd , It is working.

Comment: @GopalVerma  You are welcome.  Nice data, btw.

Answer (score 5):

Does

```
ListLinePlot[Partition[data, Floor[Length[data]/3]]]
```

do what you seek for?

Comment: Sorry,It is not working.

Comment: Joining line (highlighted by yellow square: updated figure) still present in graph.

Comment: @GopalVerma It [does work](https://imgur.com/a/6ZAcJ).

Answer (score 5):

```
data = {{0, 0}, {0.5, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 8.5}, {4, 10}, {0, 0}, {0.5, 4}, {1, 7}, {2, 9.5}, {4, 12}, {0, 0}, {0.5, 5}, {1, 9}, {2, 12}, {4, 18}};
```

By splitting the data separate curves are obtained

```
ListLinePlot[TakeList[data,
                      Length /@ Split[Module[{i = 0, prev = -∞},
                       Table[If[prev < (prev = j), i, ++i], {j, data[[All, 1]]}]]]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
(* positions where new curve start *)
pos = Position[UnitStep[Differences[data[[All, 1]]]], 0][[All, 1]]

ListLinePlot[TakeList[data,
                      Append[Differences[Join[{0}, pos]], UpTo[∞]]]]
```

Comment: I think you meant `Take[List ... ]`.

Comment: @Themis No, `TakeList` is new in 11.2

Comment: Thanks, But I don't have  Math. 11.2 so can u suggest any other option for that.

Comment: @Coolwater Good to know, I am still in 11.1.1.

Comment: @GopalVerma In older versions replace `TakeList` by ``Internal`PartitionRagged``

Comment: When I replace `TakeList` with ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` in the second approach, I get an error.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to insert a Null element where you want a break in the line:

```
data2 = {{0, 0}, {0.5, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 8.5}, {4, 10}, Null, 
  {0, 0}, {0.5, 4}, {1, 7}, {2, 9.5}, {4, 12}, Null, 
  {0, 0}, {0.5, 5}, {1, 9}, {2, 12}, {4, 18}};
ListLinePlot[data2]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1). Or alternatively: `ListLinePlot[Riffle[data, Null, 6]]`